# Type alias in scala for use in a separate package

Tags: scala, package, type-alias

I have two files, `Vec3.scala` and `Main.scala`. In `Vec3.scala`, I define the `Vec3` case class that implements all sorts of nice operators like `+`, `unary_-`, dot product, and so on. Since I will be using both colors and points in the project I am working on, my C++ instincts want me to type alias `Vec3` as `Color` and `Point3` like so:

```
// Vec3.scala
package vec3

final case class Vec3(x: Float, y: Float, z: Float) {
  ...math functions...
}

type Color = Vec3
type Point3 = Vec3
```

However, when I attempt to compile using `sbt`, I get the following error that I somewhat expected:

```
expected class or object definition
type Color = Vec3
^
```

I assume this is because these type aliases do not reside in a class or object, but I don't want them to since I would much prefer `Color` and `Point3` to have the same ease of use as `Vec3` itself. If I was using C++, I'd just put these definitions in a header file and call it a day, but alas. Is there a way to do this in Scala, without having the users of my `vec3` package make these type aliases themselves every time they are used in a file? Or is there some nifty Scala maneuver that solves this problem in a different way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

type aliases can't exist outside of a class, trait or object in scala 2. Define them in the [package object](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/package-objects.html) instead.

Comment: Other option is to use an object like a package, for example I would put all those three inside a `object model`